# Canadian anthology: includes cannibals in Newfoundland; time-travelling stock traders; etc

Tags: short-stories, dystopia, story-identification

Looking for the title of a book published in the late nineties. It was an anthology of science fiction short stories by Canadian authors, where the stories had Canadian involvement, either via location or characters.

Some of the stories included:

- an Adam and Eve couple in an enclosed environment while the outside environment is dying
- an elderly male photographer who uses his artistic abilities to remove or add people to pictures based on someone's wish
- an American tracks down a Canadian who has the ability to predict future stock prices and sells that information-the American finds out he's a time traveler from the future
- a female living in what she thinks is an enclosed habitat the size of Southern Ontario as protection from environmental collapse discovers it's actually an enormous spaceship run by a few elite people
- Americans escaping environmental collapse in the US seek refugee in Newfoundland, only to discover there are cannibals that lure refugees in
- a man grapples with the thought of foreclosure against his elderly mother's wish to commit euthanasia, as the Canadian Government pays a one time 'survival benefit' to families when their elders die (cheaper than paying for long term elder care)

***Update***
Tonight, I found the book I looked so long for. Ark of Ice: Canadian Futurefiction, Edited by Lesley Choyce, Pottersfield Press (ISBN 0-919001-73-4)

Comment: +1 for "etc" in the question title. Like these things are no big deal in Canada.

Comment: There's a whole series called "Tesseracts" which is up to volume 20. [Here's]{http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?8591} the main list of them at ISFDB (Internet SF Database). Maybe looking at the contents will help you remember.

Answer (score 3):

On 2017-11-24, the OP recorded the answer, but didn't submit it as an answer:

> Tonight, I found the book I looked so long for. Ark of Ice: Canadian Futurefiction, Edited by Lesley Choyce, Pottersfield Press (ISBN 0-919001-73-4)

[image]